# How to display an attribute that is an array of objects in twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I want to show a property that is in an array of objects.

When I try to show it in php it works. It is like this.

```
foreach($elements as $element){

echo 'Order ID ['.$element->getOrders()->getId().']</br>'; 
echo 'Show element ['.$element->getId().']</br>';
echo 'Name ['.$element->getName().']</br>';
echo 'Type ['.$element->getType().']</br>';

}
```

But I don't know how to do that in twig.

First I send this to twig...

```
return array(
     'elements' => $elements,
);
```

and in twig I try to show like this...

```
<ul>
   <li>OrderID // ElementId // Name // Type </li>
   {% for element in elements %}
   <li>{{ attribute(element, '???')}} // {{ attribute(element, 'id')}} // {{ attribute(element, 'name')}} // {{ attribute(element, 'type')}} </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then my problem is how to show this OrderID.
What I need to do in attribute or other function to show this.

Comment: Have you tried {{ element.name }} or {{ element.orders.id }} ?

Comment: `attribute(array, 'elementName')` is used when the `elementName` is dynamic, because you can't call `array.dynamicElementName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
{{ element.yourAttribute }}
```

For your orderId, if you have a ManyToOne or a OneToOne relationship, it would be :

```
{{ element.order.id }}
```

If it's a OneToMany or a ManyToMany, you should consider going through each order and get your ids. For this, [check this page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) ;-).

```
{% for order in element.orders %}
    {{ order.id }}
{% endfor %}
```